# Cannot use CTRL+Drag for making a button action in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Somethings I have a navigation controller and a view controller in my `Main.Storyboard`, but for some reason I can't create and link `IBActions` by holding down CTRL and clicking on a button on my view controller, then dragging it to my `ViewController.swift`. I could do this earlier!? What happened? Thanks

Comment: Is view controller set to your `ViewController` class on Main.Storyboard?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. How do I check that? I'm fairly new still

Answer (score 2):

Solved! I'm using a program that allows my mouse and keyboard to work between my Mac and PC without taking it out of the USB ports (works over LAN). For some reason the program is not recognizing a CTRL press which was causing the problem. After switch the keyboard to the mac itself, everything works!

Comment: Same problem, are using sharemouse?

Answer (score 1):

this happened to me before : click on the view controller and then go to utilities -> identity inspector , and check the "Class"

The class has to be the same as the file you're trying to ctrl drag into

here is the picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5451kzit16espjo/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-08%20at%2010.50.45%20AM.png?dl=0

Answer (score -1):

1. Open your xib file or storyBoard
2. Click on File’s Owner
3. Click on Identity Inspector and check class has same name as the file you’re trying to ctrl drag

This guy have awesome solution. Just need to correct your class name

[ios – can’t drag and drop item by ctrl+drag xcode](http://wisdomitsol.com/blog/ios/ios-cant-drag-and-drop-item-by-ctrl-drag-xcode)